# Problem with homeomorphic subspaces

Tags: general-topology, compactness

Are spaces $ A =  \left\{ \frac{1}{n} \,\middle|\, n \in \mathbb{N} \right\} $ and $ B =  \left\{ \frac{n+1}{n} \,\middle|\, n \in \mathbb{N} \right\} $ as subspaces of $ ( 0 , + \infty)$ homeomorphic? Are $\operatorname{Cl}(A)$ and $\operatorname{Cl}(B)$ homeomorphic?

I would say that $A$ and $B$ aren't homeomorphic because $A$ is compact and $B$ is not compact (continuous function invariants). But when it comes to $\operatorname{Cl}(A)$ and $\operatorname{Cl}(B)$ they are both compact so it would seem that they might be homeomorphic, but how do I construct the homeomorphism? The problem is the element $1$ of $B$, I can't "send" any element of A to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they are homeomorphic. Just consider$$\begin{array}{rccc}f\colon&A&\longrightarrow&B\\&x&\mapsto&x+1;\end{array}$$it's a homeomorphism.

However, $\overline A$ and $\overline B$ are *not* homeomorphic, since $\overline A$ isn't compact, whereas $\overline B$ is.

Comment: But as a subspace of $<0, +\infty> $ why isn't $ ClA$ compact? Correct me if I'm wrong but isn't  A closed in said subspace (because its complement is open in the subspace) and then $ A = ClA $? It's also bounded so it should be compact?